# How to put the title where I want

Tags: positioning, titles

I'm trying to better myself at latex, but I also want to make a standard file for doing reviewing.

So I'm trying to do something very compact but nice looking.

I achieved a pretty good result, but now I would love to do something with the title off center, with an image at the other side.

I'm using article for the documentclass, and I didn't found a substitution for \maketitle allowing me to do what I want. I also tried the renewcommand with poor result not really knowing what it was doing.

Thanks for your help!

[image: An image is better than a thousand worlds]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the `titling` package, which has many tools to customise titles.

Here is  a demo:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{titling, xcolor}
 \author{Edward Lear}
 \title{The Quangle Wangle’s Hat}
 \date{(n.\,d.)}

\pretitle{\LARGE\color{IndianRed}}
\posttitle{\hfill\raisebox{-0.4\height}{ \includegraphics[scale =0.35]{Quangle_Wangle_Hat}}\null}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\settowidth{\versewidth}{For his Hat was a hundred and two feet wide,}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\begin{altverse}
  On the top of the Crumpetty Tree\\
      The Quangle Wangle sat,\\
But his face you could not see,\\
      On account of his Beaver Hat.\\
For his Hat was a hundred and two feet wide,\\
With ribbons and bibbons on every side\\
And bells, and buttons, and loops, and lace,\\
So that nobody ever could see the face\\
            Of the Quangle Wangle Quee.
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\makeatletter         
\def\mytitle#1{
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.65\linewidth}\raggedright
{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{red}\@title}\par\bigskip 
{\bfseries\@author}\par\medskip \@date
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth,valign=t]{#1}
 \par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\title{My nice very long and impressive title}
\author{Arnaud Vivi}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\mytitle{example-image-duck}
\section{Lore ipsum}  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```